# Unity2D raycast pointing at the wrong target

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am working on a script which makes a raycast going in the direction of the mouse. But for some reason it doesn't follow the mouse, it goes directly forward.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        CastRay();
    }

    void CastRay()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity);
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is supposed to go forward. It starts at the position of the mouse.

Comment: How do you mean it 'goes forward'? That code should do a raycast from the camera position in the direction of the mouse position. Have you tried adding a line Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, Color.yellow); to see where it goes? Might also be worth putting in a breakpoint and finding out what the positions of Input.mousePosition and Camera.main are. Your code looks ok - so it might be a problem with the input values.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand this question is that you'd like to cast a ray from the player position towards mouse position in 2D. If that is not the case then you should edit your question and give more context on what exactly you want to achieve.

When I understood correctly then the answer is that you construct the wrong ray. What you're doing is casting a ray from the cameras perspective, you can think of it as casting a ray through your monitor towards the game world.

To get a ray from the player characters perspective, the ray should be from the players position towards the mouse position in screen space.

```
// get the player position in screen space
var playerScreenSpacePosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(playerPosition);

// calculate ray direction (to - from = direction)
var rayDirection = Input.mousePosition - playerScreenSpacePosition;

// if direction vectors length should be ignored then normalize
rayDirection.Normalize();

// construct the ray with the player being the origin
// (if needed could be Ray2D as well by ignoring 'Z' axis, needs converting position and direction to Vector2)
var ray = new Ray(playerPosition, rayDirection);

// cast for a hit
var hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity);

// alternatively: if the length of the raycast shall be defined by the directions magnitude
// (only if direction not normalized, otherwise the rays length will always be one)
hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, ray.direction.magnitude);
```